# Run hardcopy on a specific screen window

Tags: bash, gnu-screen, tty

I'm trying to run screen to connect to a serial port.  I want it to run a command, and then every 60 seconds I want to use hardcopy to write which is shown to a log file.

So far I've done this:

```
screen -S hub /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
```

That opens up the connection I want.  I then simply run

```
logs 2
```

Which gets the machine to output a status to the screen every 2 seconds, it just spits out a bunch of text.

I've managed to run:

```
screen -S hub -X hardcopy
```

a couple of time, but sometimes I end up with multiple screens (not even sure why) and if I do ^A ", I get a list of 2-3 windows.  The fist is ttyUSB0 and then there are usually 1 or 2 bash windows.

How can I get it to run the hardcopy command on ttyUSB0 (window 0, I believe) automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was the -p options.

```
screen -r hub -p 0 -X hardcopy
```

This allows me to send to the screen I want.  Also figured out Ctrl-a d to go back to shell without making a new screen, which helps.